# Tree Stable Timer in Bitbucket Pipelines?

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm investigating the possibility of replacing a complex Buildbot-based CI server with Bitbucket Pipelines for [running tests and deployments](https://blog.revolucija.hr/building-testing-and-deploying-django-app-with-bitbucket-pipelines-32868e12a472) for a Python-based application.

I'm new to Pipelines, but it seems to have almost all the features that Buildbot has. However, the one feature I can't find is what Buildbot terms a "tree stable timer". By default, both Buildbot and Pipelines run a build whenever a new commit is found. However, because my build takes about 2 hours to run (I have a lot of tests), if someone pushes up several commits to a branch all within a couple minutes, I only want the CI server to run a build for the most recent commit. In Buildbot, this is done by setting the time value for the "tree stable timer" parameter.

I've checked [Pipeline's docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/build-test-and-deploy-with-pipelines-792496469.html), but I can't find anything quite matching this feature, but I might not be looking in the right place. How would I do this in Pipeline?

Comment: Could you provide a specific use case when this might happen? The way I see it it should be more a case of changing the workflow as oppossed to using such a feature, since in my projects when this happens I am doing something wrong xD Of course this might not be the case for your project, so I am curious as to when and how this happens so I can elaborate my thoughts on this with clear examples and arguments :)